# Omitting will in "if-will-sentence"

Tags: conditionals, construction, first-conditional

My daughter is learning if-sentences in school right now.They learned that the rule for type I sentences is "if-clause: Simple Present, main clause: will-future or (Modal + infinitive)"

How does the following sentence fit into that rule:

> If you heat ice, **it melts.**

By the rule it should be:

> If you heat ice, it **will melt.**

Why is there "melts" used instead? What rule is applicable?

BTW: I would be sorry, if I triggered a duplicate...